# Facebook: can I set a default tab / application for users that have already liked the page

Tags: facebook

I know that I can set the default tab / application for all users that haven't liked my page yet. But is it possible to set a default tab for those users, that have already liked it? Cause now it takes them to the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is posible.